# How to get response after http request

Tags: go, goquery

I'm studying Go and am a real newbie in this field.

I am facing a problem when I try to copy some value.

What I am doing is:

> 1. I want to get some response in [response] using httpRequest.

```
httpClient := &http.Client{}
response, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

> 2. After that, I want to save the stored value in response at 'origin.txt'

```
origin_ ,_:= ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
f_, err := os.Create("origin.txt")
f_.Write(origin_);
```

> 3. And I want to get a specific value by using goquery package.

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(response.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
doc.Find(".className").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    w.WriteString("============" + strconv.Itoa(i) + "============")
    s.Find("tr").Each(func(i int, s_ *goquery.Selection) {
    fmt.Println(s_.Text())
    w.WriteString(s_.Text())    
    })
}
```

)

But in this case, I can get a value exactly what I want from 2) but cannot get anything from 3).

At first, I think the problem is, the response object at 3) is affected by 2) action. Because it is a reference object.

So I tried to copy it to another object and then do it again.

```
origin := *response
```

but, I got the same result as first.

What should I do?
How can I assign a reference value to another one by its value?

Should I request it twice for each attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>I actually don't see where you use shared resources between 2 and 3.</s>

However that being said `origin := *response` won't buy you much. The data (`response.Body`) is a `io.ReadCloser`. The `ioutil.ReadAll()` will consume and store all the data that the stream has. You only get to do this once.

However you have the data stored in `origin`. If you need another `io.Reader` for that data (say for case 3), then you can make that byte slice look like an `io.Reader` again: `bytes.NewReader(origin)`.

Comment: oops sorry. i changed my question... Sorry. The problem was at [response] object!

Comment: Perfect, well just use `bytes.NewReader(origin)` as I suggested then.

Comment: What a nice solution. Using ur solution [func NewReader(b []byte) *Reader] this, I can achieve my purpose. Thx!!!